Predict.boosting problem: newmfinal must be 1<newmfinal<mfinal
I'm trying to perform a prediction with the Adaboost algorithm using the predict.boosting() function of the adabag package, but an error occurs:

"Error in predict.boosting(adaboost, train01_new, newmfinal = 9) :
newmfinal must be 1<newmfinal<mfinal"

Here is the script:
install.packages("adabag")
library("adabag")
adaboost <- boosting.cv(factor_new ~ RFS +LI+SDI+LDI+DR+DBT+FCT+FII+DITP+ADCG+ADDG+ROA+ROI+ROS+ROE,data = train01_new, boos = TRUE, mfinal = 10, v=5, par=TRUE, control = rpart.control(cp=.001))
predict_adaboost_cv_train <- predict.boosting(adaboost, train01_new, newmfinal = 9)

I used newmfinal=9 as the error suggests but the error is still here.
